# How to do Exception handling in Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can I apply exception handling in Azure Data factory if some pipeline or activity fails and how can I implement exception handling by some TRY/CATCH methodologies ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you go the codeless route (not C# custom activity), then generally you use the success, error and completion (success or failure) outputs of an activity.  Route the success output to activities that run normally.  Route the error output to activities you want to execute on failure.

This is not a try/catch/finally paradigm but you can do most of what you want.

**Some things to try**

If you route two outputs to an input, this activity is only executed as a logical "and" of its inputs which can be useful.

i.e. if you have activity1, activity2 and activity3 and activity4.

Route **completion** output of activity1 to activity2 and **success** output of activity2 to activity3.
Then route **failure** output of activity1 to input of activity3.
Then route **success** output of activity1 to activity4.
This sets up the following flow

- If activity1 succeeds, activity2 and 4 are executed is executed in parallel.
- if activity1 fails, activity2 and 3 are executed in sequence.

Activity 2 can be used for cleanup because it is executed for both conditions (which can help to implement a "finally" but not quite the same).

Activity3 is similar but not the same as a "catch" - it only runs when activity1 fails and activity2 succeeds.

Activity4 is executed only on success of activity1 (like the rest of a try block).

There are lots of logical combinations you can use to get different effects.

Caution over timeouts and cancellations, these are not handled as "errors" and do not have their own output routing.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing `data factory` using `C#` `.NET` code and this is how I am implementing  and it works for me, everything is wrapped in one try catch. in the catch block you could send trace to `log file`, `database` or any other `service`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed by "[Activity dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities#activity-dependency)".

> Activity Dependency defines how subsequent activities depend on
>   previous activities, determining the condition of whether to continue
>   executing the next task. An activity can depend on one or multiple
>   previous activities with different dependency conditions.
>
> The different dependency conditions are: Succeeded, Failed, Skipped,
>   Completed.